# ASP.NET MVC3 - ActionResult rendering DotNetOpenAuth WebResponse as String

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth, asp.net-mvc-3

I've just updated my MVC2 project to run MVC3 (RC).  Everything is working as expected except for one problem.

I'm running DotNetOpenAuth, but when I go to authenticate, my page renders the string

> DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.OutgoingWebResponseActionResult

instead of authenticating (which worked in the MVC2 app)

I found this question [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943147/actionresult-redirect-renders-using-tostring), and I did what was suggested, but to no avail.

Here is a clip of my Web.Config

```
</configSections>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc"
                publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<system.web.webPages.razor>
```

What else could be causing this problem?

If it helps, here's the Controller code that was working prior to MVC3

```
    ''# <ValidateInput(False)> _  ''# this code is commented out so that it displays properly on StackOverflow - It's not really commented out in the project.
    Public Function Authenticate(ByVal go As String) As ActionResult
        Dim response As IAuthenticationResponse = openid.GetResponse()
        If response Is Nothing Then
            ''# Stage 2: user submitting Identifier
            Dim id As Identifier

            If Identifier.TryParse(Request.Form("openid_identifier"), id) Then

                Try
                    Return openid.CreateRequest(Request.Form("openid_identifier")).RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult()
                Catch ex As ProtocolException
                    ViewData("Message") = "Woops! " & ex.Message
                    Return View("Login")
                End Try

            Else

                ViewData("Message") = "Woops! Invalid identifier"
                Return View("Login")
            End If
        Else
            ''# Stage 3: OpenID Provider sending assertion response
            Select Case response.Status
                Case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated

                    If Not OpenIDService.IsOpenIdAssociated(response.ClaimedIdentifier) Then
                        ''# All of this happens if the user logging in does
                        ''# not currently have an account associated with
                        ''# their OpenId.  We probably want to handle this a
                        ''# little differently by sending them to a view that
                        ''# allows them to confirm account creation or try
                        ''# again. 
                        ''# TODO: Create an Authenticate View and a CreateUser ActionResult (without a View)
                        UserService.AddUser(response.ClaimedIdentifier, response.FriendlyIdentifierForDisplay)
                        UserService.SubmitChanges()

                        ActivityLogService.AddActivity(OpenIDService.GetOpenId(response.ClaimedIdentifier).UserID, _
                                                           ActivityLog.LogType.UserAdded, _
                                                           HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress)

                    Else
                        ActivityLogService.AddActivity(OpenIDService.GetOpenId(response.ClaimedIdentifier).UserID, _
                                                           ActivityLog.LogType.UserLogin, _
                                                           HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress)
                    End If

                    ''# Again, we want to make sure to associate the users
                    ''# actions with an entry in the ActivityLog for further
                    ''# use with Badges
                    ActivityLogService.SubmitChanges()


                    ''# Create the authentication cookie.  This cookie
                    ''# includes the AuthUserData information in the
                    ''# userData field of the FormsAuthentication Cookie.
                    Dim authUser As Authentication.AuthUserData = New Authentication.AuthUserData(OpenIDService.GetOpenId(response.ClaimedIdentifier).User)
                    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(Authentication.CustomAuthentication.CreateAuthCookie(response.ClaimedIdentifier, _
                                                                                                          authUser, _
                                                                                                          True))
                    authUser = Nothing

                    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(go) Then : Return Redirect(go)
                    Else : Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Events")
                    End If

                Case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled
                    ViewData("Message") = "Canceled at provider"
                    Return View("Login")

                Case AuthenticationStatus.Failed
                    ViewData("Message") = response.Exception.Message
                    Return View("Login")

            End Select
        End If
        Return New EmptyResult()
    End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well this seems to have solved the problem...  Should I be using a different version of DotNetOpenAuth?  My current version is **[Version - 3.4.3.10143]**

```
</configSections>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc"
                publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: You may want to upgrade to the latest DotNetOpenAuth, as the current one is v3.4.5, but it won't "solve" this problem.  DotNetOpenAuth compiles against MVC 1.0 so that it works for older installations.  Binding redirects is the right fix here.

Comment: thank you thank you! this was bugging me for quite some time. adding this to my web.config did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Just to build on chase's answer you can set oldVersion as a range, saving you writing it multiple times

```
</configSections>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /> 
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
<system.web.webPages.razor>
```